# Настройка прокси в nginx

Tags: nginx

Ни разу не пользовался Nginx, но в нём имеется прокси, при добавлении в `http {}` кода

```
server {
  listen 88;
  server_name site.ru;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header x_Forwarded-Dor $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_hodt;
    proxy_pass "http://site.ru:3000"
  }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
>
> ноя 09 18:57:11 raspberrypi nginx[1582]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:20
>
> ноя 09 18:57:11 raspberrypi nginx[1582]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
>
> ноя 09 18:57:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> ноя 09 18:57:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>
> ноя 09 18:57:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy s

Прошу помочь)

Comment: добавьте точку с запятой в `proxy_pass "http://site.ru:3000"` и уберите кавычки

Answer (score 1):

Точку с запятой после `proxy_pass` забыли...